Why are symmetric convex bodies with a smooth boundary and non-vanishing Gaussian curvature of particular interest in harmonic analysis?
I don't work in harmonic analysis or convex analysis, but in some literature of harmonic analysis, I often see the assumption that "let $K$ be a symmetric convex body with a smooth boundary and non-vanishing Gaussian curvature". Can anyone show me some important properties under this assumption or simply point me to some surveys/references that illustrate the importance of this regularity condition?

You might want to have a look at section 2.5 of "R. Schneider: Convex Bodies: the Brunn-Minkowski theory" for some results on smooth convex bodies.
The condition of smooth boundary with non-vanishing Gauss curvature implies, in particular, that the body has a smooth support function and that its surface area measure has a smooth density. So, e.g., the support function of an origin-symmetric convex bodies with this condition is in the image of the (spherical) cosine transform, that is, every such body is a generalized zonoid.
A different situation, where this smoothness assumption is critical, is for example the Aleksandrov-Fenchel inequality and its equality cases (see also arXiv:2312.12294 for a related inequality).
